# PFQuery for PFUser on iOS with a "whereKey:nearGeoPoint:" constraints leads to an internal server error

Tags: parse-platform, internal-server-error, pfquery, pfuser, geopoints

When I write a query on PFUser objects using PFUser.query(), and when I then add a geopoint constraint using `query.whereKey("geopointKeyToCompare", nearGeoPoint: geopoint)` it leads to a Parse internal server error (code 1).
If I test to add a geopoint constraint to a query that is not done on an User but on a standard object, using PFQuery(className: "className"), it works.

What can I do to have this geopoint constraint working with a query on PFUsers?

Comment: What ACLs have you set on the user class and instances?

Comment: ACLs are set to "Public read", and write is allowed for the matching user, on the _User class (and on all its instances).